# How to update table and show both new and old values in columns MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update part of a string (replace Away to Alone) and show the old and new value in a table. Im trying the following code with no success. Can someone explain how to get the expected result? I'm on MySQL 5.7

```
SELECT name AS old_music
FROM musics
WHERE name LIKE '%Away'
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE old_music REPLACE(name, 'Away', 'Alone')
WHERE name LIKE '%Away';
```

Expected result:

```
------------------------------------------------------
     old_music           |         new_music
------------------------------------------------------
    Walking Away         |      Walking Alone
------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you trying to a select or an update?

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY doesn't apply to SELECT statements... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do 2 different things at the same time. The following script might inspire you.

```
create table musics( name VARCHAR (100));
insert into musics values ('walking alone');
```

```
set @oldword = 'alone';
set @newword = 'away';
select 
  name oldName
from musics 
where name like 
  concat('%',@oldword,'%');
update musics
set name = 
    replace(
      name,
      @oldword,
      @newword) ;
select name newName from musics;
```

| oldName |
| --- |
| walking alone |

| newName |
| --- |
| walking away |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=13d0deabb9a582959485dca731bbf206)*